# How to set up trigger not to break when accessing picklist options

Tags: trigger

A trigger that was working was set up that based on a specific value which was hard coded, it did something.

The value options were changed and so the trigger won't work.

How to setup a trigger to look at a picklist without having to hard code values but it will know which item to look for regardless of the value?

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the **'Custom Settings'** here. Create a **'List'** type custom setting and provide them with the picklist values. There create two fields. One you can name as **'Value Number'** and other as **'Value Name'**. In the **'Value Names'** provide your picklist names. Then access them with the help of **'Value Number'**.

You can take the help of below links for more detail about Custom setting.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

**EDIT:**

```
List<Key_Staff_Role_List__c> CSList = Key_Staff_Role_List_c.getall().values();   //Gets all the data records from the custom setting
```

Run your trigger over the loop of the CSList and then check for your 3rd number value.

```
for(Key_Staff_Role_List__c m : CSList)
{
    If(your condition here)
    {
        Your list of actions
    }                
}
```

Comment: I created a CS List. It doesn't show me an option to create a picklist. How to create my list?

Comment: You will need to create both the fields of text type. Then click on manage button. And create different records for each picklist value.

Comment: Ok. I did. How to access it in my trigger? Key_Staff_Role_List is the custom setting and I wan to compare something to #3 in Value_Number__c

Comment: Check my EDIT part.

Comment: Helpful example. But since I do not know what to look for, how to get the 3rd value? Using a counter and check if it s at #3? Rr is there a direct way to get the 3rd option in a custom setting list? Sorry, I am still new at this.

Comment: Put a if condition that IF((M.Value_Number__c ==  3)&& (M.Value_Name__c == your other condition to check)) then run your actions.